# Slack on hose and venting for washer and dryer

Tags: dryer, washer

In our cottage have a large coat-closet near our front door -- the only place we could put a stacked washer/dryer. Plumbing is already nearby and it shares exterior wall (to place vent).

The problem: the washer/dryer would need to go above the access panel hatch into crawl space. We will only need to access that crawl space about once-per-year.

The question: Can we put the washer/dryer on wheels and keep an extra few feet of slack on the hose/vent to be able to pull it out (in order to access the crawl space) without needing to disconnect everything?[image]

Comment: I question whether that access panel can support the weight of a loaded washer and dryer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  There are even products made for this.  Its important to have locking wheels (even if you only ever lock the front two that you can access) [image]

As to adding some slack for the hose, remember that this will effect drying efficiency and add additional spaces for lint/socks to accumulate which can become a safety/fire issue.  Is it possible to rig a quick disconnect for the hose?  this would also allow for annual cleaning of the hose:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! What about on the washer?

Comment: Good point;  I would not do any kind of special disconnect on the washer and would just use quality extra long supply hoses.  The washers drain will likely just sits in a 2" wall drain and could be unhooked when the unit was rolled out.  Again you want to keep the washer drain short, to minimize standing water and not interfere with washer operation pumping water though it.

Comment: I actually don't see where your washer water or drain will plumb into the new closet?  is it plumbed yet or is that future work?

Comment: Future work. There's plumbing nearby but we'll have to add the connections/drain.If we set it up right, is this something anyone could disconnect/reconnect without too much trouble?

Comment: Unless the drain is routed by the side up to the front of the dryer, its always a stretchy 'yoga' job to get at the drain pipe or the supply handles.  Which side are you thinking of bringing the water into and drain to?  (if its the back wall, the drain length gets tricky with the machine pulled, but they don make longer drain hoses.

Comment: Got it. Presumably we could put it in the back left corner so you could access it without having to yoga behind the actual washer?